# Full text search with nautilus GUI

Tags: nautilus

When using the magnifying glass in the nautlius GUI (File 3.26.4) and a text string sometimes I get only file names containing this string, sometimes also files that have as content this string and this string is listed in bold face after the filename in the overview of search results.
How can this be regulated?
At the moment I cannot reproduce the second case, i. e. I get only file names although the option is activated (see screenshot. The folder contains files having the string "aussage" but these are not listed. "Gesamter Text" means "whole text".)
[image]